# How do I route out of a dynamic route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a dynamic route set up like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import DesktopHome from './DesktopHome'  
import WhoWeAre from './WhoWeAre'
import WhatWeDo from './WhatWeDo'
import Articles from './Articles'
import Article from './Article'
import NotFound from './NotFound'

...

<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' render={(props) => <DesktopHome {...props} api={this.state.api} acctok={this.state.acctok} />} />
        <Route path='/who-we-are' render={(props) => <WhoWeAre {...props} api={this.state.api} acctok={this.state.acctok} />} />
        <Route path='/what-we-do' render={(props) => <WhatWeDo {...props} api={this.state.api} acctok={this.state.acctok} />} />
        <Route path='/articles/:id' component={(props) => <Article {...props} api={this.state.api} acctok={this.state.acctok} />} />
        <Route path='/articles' render={(props) => <Articles {...props} api={this.state.api} acctok={this.state.acctok} />} />    
        <Route path='/not-found' component={NotFound} />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

The above code is for a navbar, when I go to 'articles/whatever' it works fine, however whenever that component renders if I try any of the links in the navbar I get 'articles/articles/whatever-component-route'

What I want to get is '/whatever-component-route'

*edit*

Added the component that displays the menu

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

class Menu extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='menu'>
                <ul>
                    <Link to='./who-we-are'>
                        <li>
                            <div className='menuitem'>
                                <img src={require('./img/Menu Items-02.svg')} />
                            </div>
                            <h2>Who we are</h2>
                        </li>
                    </Link>
                    <Link to='./what-we-do'>
                        <li>
                            <div className='menuitem'>
                                <img src={require('./img/Menu Items-04.svg')} />
                            </div>
                            <h2>What we do</h2>
                        </li>
                    </Link>
                    <Link to='./articles'>
                        <li>
                            <div className='menuitem'>
                                <img src={require('./img/Menu Items-03.svg')} />
                            </div>
                            <h2>Articles</h2>
                        </li>
                    </Link>
                    <Link to='./past-projects'>
                        <li>
                            <div className='menuitem'>
                                <img src={require('./img/Menu Items-05.svg')} />
                            </div>
                            <h2>Past projects</h2>
                        </li>
                    </Link>
                    <Link to='./contact'>
                        <li>
                            <div className='menuitem'>
                                <img src={require('./img/Menu Items-01.svg')} />
                            </div>
                            <h2>Contact</h2>
                        </li>
                    </Link>
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Menu
```

Comment: Can you show the router links for the "navbar"?

Comment: I edited the post to include the component that displays the navbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using `.` before your routes. Remove the dot from all links and it will instead start at the root. Example:

```
to="/contact"
```